# Как корректно реализовать код?

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать программу, рассчитывающую стоимость и калорийность гамбургера. Использовать ООП подход.
Есть пример работы кода:

```
// маленький гамбургер c начинкой с сыром //
var hamburger = new Hamburger(Hamburger .SIZE_SMALL, Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE);

// добавка майонеза
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger.TOPPING_MAYO);

// спрашиваем сколько калорий
console.log('Calories: ' + hamburger.calculate ());

// тут я передумал и решил добавить еще приправу
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger .TOPPING_SAUCE);

// Сколько теперь стоит?
console.log('Price with sauce:' + hamburger.calculatePrice());
```

Пробовал написать сам не очень понимаю как реализовать и рассчитывать цену и калории. Прикрепляю пример моего кода то что пытался сам написать.

```js
class Hamburger {
    constructor() {}
    static SIZE_SMALL (price,calories) {};
    static SIZE_HUGE (price,calories) {};
    static STUFFING_CHEESE (price,calories) {};
    static STUFFING_SALAD (price,calories) {};
    static STUFFING_POTATOE (price,calories) {};
    static TOPPING_SAUCE (price,calories) {};
    static TOPPING_MAYO (price,calories) {};
    addTopping (TOPPING_MAYO) {};
    calculate () {

    }
    calculatePrice () {

    }

}
//_______Размеры гамбургеров_______//
Hamburger.SIZE_SMALL(50,20);
Hamburger.SIZE_HUGE(100,40);

//_______Начинки гамбургеров_______//
Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE(10,20);
Hamburger.STUFFING_SALAD(20,5);
Hamburger.STUFFING_POTATOE(15,10);

//_______Добавки к гамбургерам_______//
Hamburger.TOPPING_SAUCE(15,0);
Hamburger.TOPPING_MAYO(20,5);

// маленький гамбургер с начинкой з сыру //
let hamburger = new Hamburger(Hamburger.SIZE_SMALL, Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE);

// добавка майонеза
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger.TOPPING_MAYO);

// спрашиваем сколько калорий
console.log('Calories: ' + hamburger.calculate ());

// тут я передумал и решил добавить еще приправу
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger .TOPPING_SAUCE);

// Сколько теперь стоит?
console.log('Price with sauce:' + hamburger.calculatePrice());
```

Comment: А что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: @EzioMercer нужно реализовать код под данную строку: let hamburger = new Hamburger(Hamburger.SIZE_SMALL, Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE). При этом SIZE_SMALL и STUFFING_CHEESE имеют свойства price, calories.

Comment: Я запутался в невозможно названиях, что такое `SIZE_HUGE` и `STUFFING_CHEESE`? Почему используется `SIZE_SMALL` как просто поле и как статическое поле? И что должны делать мистические методы?

Comment: Я полагаю что это методы(правда почему они полностью с большое буквы я не знаю, заданы по заданию). Данные методы имеют параметры price, calories.

Comment: @EzioMercer запутался в наименованиях, SIZE_HUGE случайно создал

Comment: "Я полагаю что это методы" - докончите мысль пожалуйста :) И напишите в вопрос всё задание пожалуйста, так будет понятнее всем

Comment: Просто т.к. у вас нет тела статических функций, то их вызовы не делают абсолютно ничего, у них должно быть предназначение

Comment: @EzioMercer вопрос отредактировал и конкретизировал

Comment: Говорю же вы что-то не договариваете, тепепь понятно что вам надо :) Как освобожусь изменю свой ответ

Comment: 1. Код который выше `let hamburger` и ниже объявления класса - он полностью ваш? 2. `class Hamburger` вами написан? 3. Если ответы на 1 и 2 - нет, то мне интересно, зачем сначала вызывать статический метод, а потом отправлять ссылку на него в конструктор? 4. Конструктор может принимать любое количество аргументов или только обязательных 2? 5. Конструктор выступает в роли `addTopping` или у них разная функциональность?

Comment: @EzioMercer 1.Код 'let hamburger' и ниже задан по условию задачи. 2. 'class Hamburger' написан мною.   3.-   4. Я полагаю что любое, ограничений в задание нет. 5. Я использовал конструктор так этого требовала IDE, чтобы можно было вывести корректно данную строку 'let hamburger = new Hamburger(Hamburger.SIZE_SMALL, Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE);' Но какие передавать значения в конструктор я не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
class CompositionElement {
  constructor(price, calories) {
    this.price = price;
    this.calories = calories;
  }
}

class Hamburger {
  static #SIZE_SMALL = new CompositionElement(50, 20);
  static #SIZE_HUGE = new CompositionElement(100, 40);
  static #STUFFING_CHEESE = new CompositionElement(10, 20);
  static #STUFFING_SALAD = new CompositionElement(20, 5);
  static #STUFFING_POTATOE = new CompositionElement(15, 10);
  static #TOPPING_SAUCE = new CompositionElement(15, 0);
  static #TOPPING_MAYO = new CompositionElement(20, 5);

  static get SIZE_SMALL () { return Hamburger.#SIZE_SMALL};
  static get SIZE_HUGE () { return Hamburger.#SIZE_HUGE};
  static get STUFFING_CHEESE () { return Hamburger.#STUFFING_CHEESE};
  static get STUFFING_SALAD () { return Hamburger.#STUFFING_SALAD};
  static get STUFFING_POTATOE () { return Hamburger.#STUFFING_POTATOE};
  static get TOPPING_SAUCE () { return Hamburger.#TOPPING_SAUCE};
  static get TOPPING_MAYO () { return Hamburger.#TOPPING_MAYO};

  #size = null;
  #stuff = null;
  #ingredients = [];

  constructor(...args) {
    args.forEach(this.#changeComposition.bind(this));
  }

  #changeComposition(element) {
    switch (element) {
      case Hamburger.#SIZE_SMALL:
      case Hamburger.#SIZE_HUGE:
        this.#changeSize(element);
        break;
      case Hamburger.#STUFFING_CHEESE:
      case Hamburger.#STUFFING_SALAD:
      case Hamburger.#STUFFING_POTATOE:
        this.#changeStuff(element);
        break;
      default:
        this.addTopping(element);
    }
  }

  #changeSize(size) {
    this.#size = size;
  }

  #changeStuff(stuff) {
    this.#stuff = stuff;
  }

  addTopping(topping) {
    this.#ingredients.push(topping);
  }

  calculate() {
    return this.#size.calories +
      this.#stuff.calories +
      this.#ingredients.reduce((totalCalories, ingredient) => totalCalories + ingredient.calories, 0);
  }

  calculatePrice() {
    return this.#size.price +
      this.#stuff.price +
      this.#ingredients.reduce((totalPrice, ingredient) => totalPrice + ingredient.price, 0);
  }

}

// маленький гамбургер с начинкой з сыру //
let hamburger = new Hamburger(Hamburger.SIZE_SMALL, Hamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE);

// добавка майонеза
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger.TOPPING_MAYO);

// спрашиваем сколько калорий
console.log('Calories: ' + hamburger.calculate ());

// тут я передумал и решил добавить еще приправу
hamburger.addTopping(Hamburger .TOPPING_SAUCE);

// Сколько теперь стоит?
console.log('Price with sauce:' + hamburger.calculatePrice());
```

Ответ на вопрос из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485651/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1485669?noredirect=1#comment2662930_1485669):

> Для чего мы используем `get` и почему возвращем `Hamburger.#Private_Static_Field`

В поле `static #Private_Static_Field` я храню созданный экземпляр класса `CompositionElement`, в приватном статическом поле. Это нужно по нескольким причинам:

1. Мы сохранем экземпляр класса и нам не нужно его пересоздавать каждый раз
2. Можно использовать строгое сравнение при передачи этого объекта в любой метода класса. Например это используется в `switch`, чтобы понять что именно передали нам в конструктор. Если бы я возвращал каждый раз `new CompositionElement(...)`, то сравнение было бы невозмжно, т.к. у каждого была своя ссылка
3. Поле приватное, чтобы к нему не было доступа извне класса
4. Поле статическое чтобы статические методы могли к ниму обращаться

Я использую [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) модификатор доступа чтобы нельзя было изменить извне. Простой пример как это помогает:

```js
class WithoutGetModificator {
  static Field = 'field';
}

console.log(WithoutGetModificator.Field);

WithoutGetModificator.Field = 'modified field';

console.log(WithoutGetModificator.Field);

class WithGetModificator {
  static get Field() {return 'field'};
}

console.log(WithGetModificator.Field);

WithGetModificator.Field = 'modified field';

console.log(WithGetModificator.Field);
```

Comment: @Smile Посмотрите пожалуйста, это то что вам надо?

Comment: да это то, если вас не затруднит могли бы расписать как работает ваш код

Comment: @Smile Можете пожалуйста сказать какая часть именно вызывает трудности, потому что там есть очевидные места, которые если расписывать, то долго :)

Comment: 1.Объясните пожалуйста данную строку 'static get SIZE_SMALL () { return Hamburger.#SIZE_SMALL}' Для чего мы используем "get" и зачем в функции "SIZE_SMALL" мы возвращаем "Hamburger.#SIZE_SMALL".

Comment: @Smile Добавил ответ на ваш вопрос